# Flipping a 2D "image" which is stored in a 1D array in F#

Tags: f#, kinect

I am working with Kinect and am trying to take in depth data and process it.

Essentially, when I process depth frames from the Kinect I want to save 2- the front depth data of a player and the back.  I then need to flip round the back data so that it can then be used to build a 3D model of the player.

The problems I am having is flipping this back data around.

I have the depth data in the form of of a 1D array of length (320*240 = 76800) for which I was planing to flip each row (320 positions in the array) to reverse the image.

```
let mutable flipped = Array.create (320*240) 0
for y=0 to 239 do
    for x=0 to 319 do
        let n = ((y)* 320 + x)
        flipped.[n] <- depths.[(320*(y+1))-(n+1)]

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DepthsMax:" + Array.max(depths).ToString())
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FlippedMax:" + Array.max(flipped).ToString())
```

The depths array contains the data I am trying to flip round, however, this code makes the flipped array consist entirely of 0s.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: For arrays, `mutable` makes the reference mutable. The elements are _always_ mutable. So, it's unnecessary in this case.

Comment: You can replace `Array.create _ 0` with `Array.zeroCreate _`.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tips guys, still trying to get to grips with f#! Very useful thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that you don't need for `flipped` to be mutable since you never reassign it (you only modify it).

On to the problem itself.  Given `n = 320*y + x`, you are looking at index:

```
320 * (y+1) - n - 1
= 320 * y + 320 - (320 * y + x) - 1
= 319 - x
```

Thus, you're only ever accessing data from the first row.  You want to be accessing index `y*320 + (319-x)` or `320*(y+1) - (x+1)`, not `320*(y+1) - (n+1)`.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much. I always reckon the hardest problems (for me anyway) to crack in programming are the silly mistakes you have been staring at for days convincing yourself that you cant see the error! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, row indices are unchanged and data in each row should be reversed:

```
for row=0 to 239 do
  for col=0 to 319 do
    flipped.[320*row+col] <- depths.[320*row+319-col]
```